# $\theta '' = \frac{a}{R}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

[image]
Assume that this is a general circular motion where $\theta$ is a function of time. I've derived some equations below and found that the angular velocity in the end is zero. Which step of my derivation is wrong?

$ \vec{p}(t) = R cos(\theta) \hat{x} + R sin(\theta) \hat{y} ......(1)$
$ \vec{v}(t) = -R sin(\theta) \dot{\theta} \hat{x} + Rcos(\theta) \dot{\theta} \hat{y} ......(2)$
$ \vec{a}(t) = -R [cos(\theta) \dot{\theta}^2 + sin(\theta) \ddot{\theta}] \hat{x} + R[-sin(\theta) \dot{\theta}^2 + cos(\theta) \ddot{\theta}] \hat{y} ......(3)$
$ (2): |\vec{v}| = R \dot{\theta} $
$ a = \frac{dv}{dt} = R \ddot{\theta} ......(4) $
$ (3): |\vec{a}| = R \sqrt{\dot{\theta}^4 + \ddot{\theta}^2} $
$ \Rightarrow \frac{a^2}{R^2} = \dot{\theta}^4 + \ddot{\theta}^2 $
$ (4): \ddot{\theta} = \frac{a}{R} $
$ \Rightarrow \frac{a^2}{R^2} = \dot{\theta}^4 + \frac{a^2}{R^2} $
$ \Rightarrow \dot{\theta}^4 = 0 $

Comment: Even when I put the content of your "question" into LaTeX, it is still a jumbled mess. What are you trying to ask? (It is not forbidden to use natural language in physics, you know?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(4)$ is false. Note that by the same logic, $v = \frac{\mathrm{d}|\vec{x}|}{\mathrm{d}t} = \partial_tR = 0$.

Please note that you should ask about a specific physics concept and not just throw "Here's a calculation, show me where I'm wrong" at us.

Comment: Sorry. I thought the math would be the most succinct way of asking the question since I didn't know what physics concept I was missing.